# .wav audio file to text conversion Android

Tags: android, wav

I have recorded an Audio file in .wav format in Android. I did this by adding a header to the .raw file initially recorded. 
I wanted to convert this audio file in text format. Is there a way to do so. Or are there any libraries present. I don't want to do this conversion in real-time(Google Speech API). I want to give the recorded audio file(.wav) as the input and get text as the output. Can anyone help?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need an ASR library (Automatic Speech Recognition).
There are two different kind of libraries, Online and offline.
Online solutions can understand free speech. 
Offline solutions are used for specific keywords and you have to build and internal dictionary. 
But for both (as far as I know) you have to pay. Take a look for Google ASR or Nuance ASR solutions.